# Assertion issue in Java and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit

I am using Java, Selenium Webdriver and Junit. Doing simple verification of title of Google , But it throws exception when Assertion fails I mean when title does not match.

Code :

```
public static void verifyTitle(String expectedTitle) {
        //get the title of the page
        String actualTitle = Base.getdriver().getTitle();

        // verify title
        assertThat(actualTitle, equalTo(expectedTitle));
    }
```

I am calling in main method : `verifyTitle("Hello");`

Output :

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError:  Expected:
> "Hello"
>      but: was "Google"    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)     at
> org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)  at
> org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)  at
> Modules.Help.verifyTitle(Help.java:161)   at
> Modules.Help.GUI(Help.java:152)   at Modules.Help.main(Help.java:29)
```

It is checking everything proper but not sure why throwing exception? How can I print message like **"Title does not match"** instead of this exception.

Comment: You can add a message in assertion: `assertThat("Title does not match", actualTitle, equalTo(expectedTitle));`

Comment: @bigdestroyer - I tried your given code. But still exception is there.

Comment: If you use JUnit assertions, I'm afraid that you can't avoid the assertion error. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @bigdestroyer - I do not want to avoid error , I just want to show it in nice manner to user. For ex : Print message that title does not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That is expected behavior of JNunit**! It will always throw exception when assert failed. Here is description of the method [assertThat](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)):

> Asserts that actual satisfies the condition specified by matcher. If
>   not, an AssertionError is thrown with information about the matcher
>   and failing value.

You can try/catch the Error then print the message that you want.

```
try {
    assertThat("a", equalTo("a"));
    System.out.println("Title matched");
}    
catch(Error e) {
    System.out.println("Title does not match");
}
```

Comment: @Buaban - It is not working for me. Even after putting try/catch I am getting same exception.:(

Comment: @Henry Thank you. I'm confused with C#. I've just updated my answer.

Comment: @Buaban - Thanks for answer update. It is working for me now. Can you please also guide me that if both title matches then how can I print success message while using assertion?

Comment: @HelpingHands You can add print method under the assertion. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Buaban - Perfect Man. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Write this:

```
if (!Objects.equals(actualTitle, expectedTitle))
  System.out.println("Title doesn't match.");
```

But why would you want to do that?

Selenium tests inform you when something is not as expected, automatically. Throwing an AssertError means failure, and that failure can be displayed nicely to humans. When you use System.out.println, you just print something, but the program continues as if there were no error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thing is I always prefer your given method to verify title and many other string. But in web I have seen most of example for verification are using Assert method so I thought let me try this one. Am I doing anything wrong? Or is there any particular situation where we should use assertions?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the try catch, have a look here: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/ I think it could help you ;)

Comment: Why would one want to catch a test failure?

Comment: He is getting and exception, and he want to catch it, so I think this way could help him, but I could be wrong :p

Answer (score 0):

Just study the javadoc for [assertThat](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(java.lang.String,%20T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)):

*Asserts that actual satisfies the condition specified by matcher. If not, an AssertionError is thrown with information about the matcher and failing value.*

The point is that when you are running with JUnit, the exception is catched; and translated to some nice printout. So, when you are working outside of a JUnit @Test; well; then some other code needs to try/catch ...